# How to unset video in VideoView on Android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I can set the video using `VideoView#setVideoPath` or `VideoView#setVideoURI`. How do I unset it? Setting it to `""` or `null` make it show `Can't play this video`.

Comment: have you tried not using method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath("");  // mVideoView.setVideoPath(null);
```

or

```
mVideoView.setVideoURI(""); // mVideoView.setVideoURI(null);
```

Then it vll shows the  "can't play this video alert" message.That we can handle by using a video view listener

below listener do's that ,

```
mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.d("video", "setOnErrorListener ");
                return true;
            }
        });
```

For more info see [Android Document about Media Player](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html#onError%28android.media.MediaPlayer,%20int,%20int%29)